# Display Centered Text in a time range (between f.e. 0800 and 1000) at the top of the Chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Couldn't find a way to display a centered Text (no label) in a time range (between f.e. "0800" and "1000") at the top of the Chart.

Would appreciate some help here.

Many thanks.

Update -----------

Find myself an incomplete solution :

```
tSBLN = time(timeframe.period, "0330-0331")

labelSBLN = if (not na(tSBLN))
    label.new(bar_index, high, yloc=yloc.abovebar, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_none, textalign=text.align_center, size=size.normal)
label.set_text(id=labelSBLN, text="SB")
```

Would someone be so kind and explain me how I can set this label, not abovebar but at the top of the Chart or move him vertically upward ?

Comment: What do you mean by "no label"? You don't want to do this with a label?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just need to display text with no box around (if possible), hope I answered your question.

Comment: you can create transparent label without borders with color = color(na)

Comment: @starr-lucky thank you, I know that, but what I don't know is how to center the text at the top of the chart in a range (0800-1200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

Hereafter how I could solve it :

```
//@version=5
indicator("[IND] Range", overlay = true)

// InSession() determines if a price bar falls inside the specified session
InSession(sess) => na(time(timeframe.period, sess)) == false

var bool showRange = input(false, title="See Range", tooltip = "[1100-1400 EST]", group="RANGE")

titleRange = "Range"

range_Range = input.session("1100-1400", title=titleRange, group="RANGE") // Define the start and end time of your range

color_Range = color.new(color.gray,0)

bgcolor(InSession(range_Range)[1] and showRange ? color_Range: na, editable=false)

tRange = time(timeframe.period, "1230-1231") // Define the middle of the range in order to center your text horizontally in the plotted (bgcolor) range

plotshape(not na(tRange) and showRange ? high: na, style=shape.square, text=titleRange, size=size.large, location=location.top, textcolor=color.black, color=color.new(color.gray,100)))
```